# wordpress site url not working for localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I was about to set my **localwordpress** to a online site. So I set my site url and home url to that sites name.

Now something went wrong and I was about to check my **wp admin** and I couldnt get in. I went in to the database to set it back to how it normal was for me. So I set the site url to localhost/wordpress and the home url to localhost.

Now I can see the styles but not my content or images. I am using **xampp** if that matters. Does anyone knows how i can fix this.? Btw I also can't go into wp-admin.

Comment: i just got into the wp-admin and can change it now but i cant find what the default settings where because it is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the wordpress URL to http://localhost/wordpress and the site url to http://localhost/wordpress/home and everything works now.